# Как выбрать один символ через несколько?

Tags: python

`text = "Текст123"`

Что нужно сделать что бы через 2 символа писался один?

`Вывод: Тс2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте срезы

Вот сайт с описанием

> https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/indeksy-i-srezy.html

```
text[::3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Aльтернативное решение:

```
''.join(j for i, j in enumerate("Текст123") if i % 3 == 0)
```

Comment: зачем такие сложности, когда есть срезы? ;)

Comment: @MaxU просто альтернативное решение ;)